# Overriding Magento Sitemap Model Class

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, sitemaps

I try to override `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product` class. Here is my files:

File \magento\app\etc\modules\Own_Sitemap.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Own_Sitemap>
                <active>true</active>
                <codepool>local</codepool>
            </Own_Sitemap>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

File \magento\app\code\local\Own\Sitemap\etc\config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
    <modules>
        <Own_Sitemap>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Own_Sitemap>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sitemap>
                <catalog_resource>
                    <rewrite>
                        <product>Own_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product</product>
                    </rewrite>
                </catalog_resource>
            </sitemap>
        </models>
    </global>
    </config>
```

File \magento\app\code\local\Own\Sitemap\Model\Resource\Catalog\Product.php

```
class Own_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product extends Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product
{
    /**
     * Get product collection array
     *
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCollection($storeId)
    {
        /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
        if (!$store) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
            ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()), array($this->getIdFieldName()))
            ->join(
                array('w' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_website')),
                'main_table.entity_id = w.product_id',
                array()
            )
            ->where('w.website_id=?', $store->getWebsiteId());

        $storeId = (int)$store->getId();

        /** @var $urlRewrite Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Url_Rewrite_Interface */
        $urlRewrite = $this->_factory->getProductUrlRewriteHelper();
        $urlRewrite->joinTableToSelect($this->_select, $storeId);

        $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'visibility',
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds(), 'in'
        );
        $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'status',
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getVisibleStatusIds(), 'in'
        );

        $entries = $this->_loadEntities();
        $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'inchoo_meta_robots', array(200, 201), 'in');
        $noindex = $this->_loadEntities();

        foreach ($entries as $k => $v){
            if (array_key_exists($k, $noindex)) {
                unset($entries[$k]);
            }
        }
        return $entries;
    }

}
```

When I try to generate new sitemap, application stiil use Mage class. I tried to remove the cache, but it did not help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure no other modules has rewritten that class?

Answer (score 0):

Use below config instead of above to rewrite model

```
    #File \magento\app\code\local\Own\Sitemap\etc\congif.xml

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Own_Sitemap>
                <version>0.1</version>
            </Own_Sitemap>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <sitemap>                    
                    <rewrite>
                        <resource_catalog_product>Own_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product</resource_catalog_product>
                    </rewrite>                   
                </sitemap>
            </models>
        </global>
    </config>
```

Comment: Problem still not solved.

Comment: I modified above code, try this

Comment: Does not work. Thank you for trying

Comment: I have gone through the above code and tested it on the same module to rewrite and its working perfectly, any thing else which you want to tell, me any error, some what else

Comment: I set xdebug breakpoints and I see that magento still use core class. In Configuration > Advanced > Advanced this block is enabled http://i.imgur.com/UYvPUWa.png

Comment: Can this happen because I have message "One or more of the Indexes are not up to date"?

Comment: Ok module is ok, how you are testing can you brief?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code in File \magento\app\etc\modules\Own_Sitemap.xml

**From**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Own_Sitemap>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Own_Sitemap>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**To**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Own_Sitemap>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Own_Sitemap>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Note:** Magento will first take the  node value (watch the upper case P in the node name).Then it is must be `codePool`

Replace your code in File \magento\app\code\local\Own\Sitemap\etc\config.xml

**From**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Own_Sitemap>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Own_Sitemap>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sitemap>
                <catalog_resource>
                    <rewrite>
                        <product>Own_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product</product>
                    </rewrite>
                </catalog_resource>
            </sitemap>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**To**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Own_Sitemap>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Own_Sitemap>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sitemap_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Own_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
            </sitemap_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
 </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above Answer is not working :
correct configuration will be

```
<global>
  <models>    
    <sitemap_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <catalog_product>Own_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product</catalog_product>
        </rewrite>
    </sitemap_resource>
  </models>
</global>
```